# Is there a formula to count the number of solutions for $x_1 x_2 ... x_m=n$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I know there is a formula to count the number of solutions of $x_1+x_2+...x_m=n$ and $x_i>0$ for $i=1,2...m$, but i was wondering if there is a (nice looking) formula for the number of solutions of $x_1 x_2...x_m=n$ for $x_i>0$, $x_i \in \mathbb{Z}$, $i=1,2...m$ .

Comment: Where will the x1,x2 belongs

Comment: I am sorry i forgot to mention that $x_i$ are integers.

Comment: Suppose n=12 then if m is fixed then ans is different from if m is not fixed..like if m=2 then $12=2*3*2$ can't be a solution, and only $1*12$ ,$3*4$ ,$2*6$ will be included.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $m=2$, then the number of solutions to $x_1 \cdot x_2 = n$ is equal to the number of divisors $\sigma(n)$ of $n$.

If we know the prime factorization of $n$, say $n = \prod_{i=1}^r p_i^{a_i}$, then $\sigma(n)$ can be computed efficiently via the formula

$$ \sigma(n) = \prod_{i=1}^r (a_i+1) $$

However if you don't know the prime factorization of $n$, you're out of luck. So in general, there is no formula to efficiently compute the number of solutions to your equation, even in the simplest case $m=2$.